# how I can add extra my attribute into bootstrapTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, bootstrap-table

I used bootstrapTable.js plugin 
https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table
to create datatable ,I  populated table by Json

but I need to control in my td tag as add some extra attribute in td tag
as I wrote in my code "data-symbole" attribute
,but the plugin remove it 
can anyone help me please

```js
var x = 
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "test0",
        "price": "$0"
        ,"pricesymbole":"$"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test1",
        "price": "$1"
      ,"pricesymbole":"$"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test2",
        "price": "$2"
      ,"pricesymbole":"$"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "test3",
        "price": "$3"
      ,"pricesymbole":"$"
    }
];

$(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: x
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr id="tr_{{id}}">
            <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
            <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
            <th data-field="price" data-symbole="pricesymbole">Item Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `formatter` option is useful in your case:

```js
var x = 
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "test0",
        "price": "0"
        ,"pricesymbole":"$ "
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test1",
        "price": "1"
      ,"pricesymbole":"￥"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test2",
        "price": "2"
      ,"pricesymbole":"$ "
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "test3",
        "price": "3"
      ,"pricesymbole":"￥"
    }
];

$(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: x
    });
});

function priceFormatter(value, row) {
    return row.pricesymbole + value;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr id="tr_{{id}}">
            <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
            <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
            <th data-field="price" data-formatter="priceFormatter">Item Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: hi ,I want add any attribute in general

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks. Via the formatter you van access all the data in the JSON.